# How can I sort my list?

Tags: sorting

I have a matrix

[image: 1],

and I want to sort it to obtain this matrix

[image: 1].

I tried `SortBy`, but I can only do it for 2 dimensional matrix. Can anyone help me?

Comment: 1) Post your matrix in form of an MMA code; 2) describe what is the general rule you want to employ in the sorting (I guess you don't just want to manually switch the columns).

Comment: You want to sort it by the last element of the column?

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to do it is to strip off the outer brackets, sort, and then replace the outer brackets.

```
m = {{{4, 2, 2}, {27, 4, 1}, {12, 44, 6}, {32, 11, 11}, {44, 21, 5}}};
sorted = {SortBy[m[[1]], Last]}
```

> `{{{27, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {44, 21, 5}, {12, 44, 6}, {32, 11, 11}}}`

```
sorted // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 2):

I would use the operator form:

```
m = {{{4, 2, 2}, {27, 4, 1}, {12, 44, 6}, {32, 11, 11}, {44, 21, 5}}};

SortBy[Last] /@ m
```

> ```
> {{{27, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {44, 21, 5}, {12, 44, 6}, {32, 11, 11}}}
> ```